# c# winforms multiline textbox to mailto: body

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, mailto, email-body

I have tried to find an answer to this particular question, and I've tried replacing all \r\n with `<br>` but it didn't work. I might be doing something wrong though.

What I want is to get a multiline textbox's content into a mail body after the user clicks on a button.

This is an example of what my textbox result is vs how it comes out in the mail body:

Multiline textbox content in my program:

 MVT

6B123/26/SERNC.LAX

AD1445/1447 EA1913 LPA

PX328

Mailto body:

MVT6B123/26/SERNC.LAXAD1445/1447EA1913LPAPX328

I've tried this with .Text.Replace too but it didn't work with `<br>` as in my example here below (to be fair I'm pretty new to coding).

```
string mailResult = txtMvtResult.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br>");
string command = "mailto:firstname.lastname@organization.com?subject=MVT&body=" + mailResult + "";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(command);
```

Does anyone know how I can make my mail body look like a multiline textbox's content?

Best regards,
Rickard

Comment: `string command = Uri.EscapeUriString("mailto:firstname.lastname@organization.com?subject=MVT&body=" + txtMvtResult.Text); Process.Start(command);`

Comment: Or `string command = "mailto:[...]" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(txtMvtResult.Text);`

Comment: Cheers, this is exactly what I was looking for! I've gotta read up on Uri.EscapeUriString method. Have a good one.